# Google OAuth - Is using "anonymous" as key and secret insecure?

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-oauth

I have been experimenting with some scripts in the Google Spreadsheets environment, and have been trying to take a document, convert it to a PDF, and then e-mail it. In the process, I've stumbled across a few snippets of code that used the following lines:

```
/* This snippet taken from : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4169590 - I would include my version of this code here, but since I have not posted on Stack Exchange much yet, I am limited as to what I can include in my post. */
oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
```

My question is, **is using the anonymous key and secret phrase a potential security risk for those running my script?**

In other words, could someone who has the same key and phrase access the data I have authorized for the anonymous account with the "anonymous" secret?

I've spent some time looking around for this in other posts, and haven't seen anyone else ask this question. It very well could be that this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only identifies the application (your script) as I understand it that's for unregistered apps so should be fine.